# How to import a javascript modules in rails 5 with webpacker gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, webpack

Good day all,

Am pretty new to Vue.js and im experimenting with Vue.js in rails 5 using the webpacker gem. In a new rails 5 app i included the webpacker gem to Gem file and installed webpacker and then vue.js like so

```
 rails webpacker:install
 rails webpacker:install:vue
```

Both components installed and when i start the servers all is well and it displays "Hello Vue" etc. FYI i also use "foreman" gem to start both rails server and webpack-dev server

Now the thing is im trying to include "GoogleMapsApi.js" into this project but am finding it very hard to import this module.This is a javascript module thats on Github which basically loads Google Maps Api. I downloaded and copied it into the below directory

```
{Rails.root}/app/javascript/packs
```

https://gist.github.com/mavame/b833b50085dc856acbccbb34ab1dbe92

This is how my "app.vue" looks like. ps this file was created when i installed vue with webpack install command

```
   <template>
     <div id="app">
       <div id="map_canvas"></div>
     </div>
  </template>

<script>   
    export default {
      el: '#app',
      data: function () {
        return {
          message: "Helloooooo Vue!"
        }
      },
      mounted(){

        const gmapApi = new GoogleMapsApi();
          gmapApi.load().then(() => {

        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-26.29217,28.070820000000026)
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        });
      }
    }
</script>
```

Now i do include this module inside application.js like so

```
     import 'GoogleMapsApi';
```

So when i run foreman i get this error.

```
    ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'GoogleMapsApi' in '/home/diego/Sites/vue-demo/app/javascript/packs'
```

The actual app that i'm on pulls both vue and google maps in using cdn script tags but i found these to be un reliable because sometimes google maps loads sometimes it doesnt.

So im trying the webpacker but if not even able to do it inside a new app imagine the existing one.

Please Help Thanks

Comment: your application.js try to find the GoogleMapsApi.js file here: `.../vue-demo/app/javascript/packs`. Did you put this file in the packs folder ?

Comment: I have "google-maps-api" folder which contains the "GoogleMapsApi.js" and i also created a "index.js"

Comment: How can i edit this post ? I dont see a link anywhere

Comment: I also found this https://medium.com/statuscode/introducing-webpacker-7136d66cddfb and tried it but i still cant manage to import :(